# why does boost::any forbid the forwarding of const&&?

Tags: c++, c++11, boost

Here is the relevant code:

```
// Perfect forwarding of ValueType
template<typename ValueType>
any(ValueType&& value
    , typename boost::disable_if<boost::is_same<any&, ValueType> >::type* = 0 // disable if value has type `any&`
    , typename boost::disable_if<boost::is_const<ValueType> >::type* = 0) // disable if value has type `const ValueType&&`
  : content(new holder< typename decay<ValueType>::type >(static_cast<ValueType&&>(value)))
{
}
```

For all I know, a copy constructor could be used to construct from  a const&&. I use boost 1.55.0.

Comment: Note there's `template<typename ValueType> any(const ValueType & value)` which will match const rvalues as well.

Comment: @dyp Yeah, but why not just forward them, what's the big deal?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a fix for https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/9215:

> #### Infinite loop when `any` constructor called for `const any&&`
>
> ```
> #include <boost/any.hpp>
> #include <string>
> const boost::any getBoolVal()
> {
>     return false;
> }
> int main()
> {
>     boost::any vals[] = {1.0, std::string("1m"), getBoolVal()};
> }
> ```

So it looks like the intent is to exclude `any const&&` from the forwarding constructor; the fact that it excludes all `const` rvalues is a side effect, harmless because those will be handled by the `ValueType const&` copying constructor.

Personally, I would have gone for

```
typename disable_if<is_same<any,
    typename remove_cv<typename remove_reference<ValueType>::type>::type>>::type
```

which correctly handles `volatile` rvalues as well - not that I've ever seen one of those in the flesh.

Comment: tangent: aren't you missing a bunch of `typename`s in there?

Comment: @Dave yeah, I'm a bit lazy.

Comment: @ecatmur Why not just decay ValueType btw?

Comment: @user1095108 `boost::decay` doesn't remove cv, unfortunately. `std::decay` would work fine.